# wrong second argument type Found andriod.content.Dialoginterface.onClicklistener, required andrid.content.Context

Tags: java

Hello I'm  trying to get an list of classes to be saved so when the app is closed and reopened the content will still be there. I tried to save the array to another java page but I keep getting this error.

```
//Main Java
    builder.setPositiveButton("Add Class", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    String ClassesAdded = ClassET.getText().toString();
                    adapter.add(ClassesAdded);
                    ClassET.setText("");
                    **FileHelper.writeData(classarray, this);//line giving me error**


            }
        });

//FileHelper
public class FileHelper {
    public static final String FILENAME = "listinfo.dat";
    public static void writeData(ArrayList<String> classarray, Context context){
        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = context.openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
            oos.writeObject(classarray);
            oos.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error is because `this` refers to the `OnClickListener` in that scope but the function expects a Context. If your activity (wherever the builder call is) is named `MainActivity` you would need to use `MainActivity.this` there to use the right class instance, like this:

```
FileHelper.writeData(classarray, MainActivity.this);
```

Obviously replace `MainActivity` with your actual class name if that's not what it's called...